# No debugging symbols found

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb, debug-symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging using gdb - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790407/debugging-using-gdb-best-practices)

I have just one `.cpp` file and I compile it with g++ on ubuntu terminal.

Then when I call `gdb myProgram`, I get `no debugging symbols found`.

I need to step through the code, to debug it. I don't know how to make it work.

I know how to use `gdb`, but not sure how to compile my `.cpp` file so that it has debug information for gdb to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compile with the `-g` flag. See here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html